# scala - how to separate `reactions` in a method

Tags: scala

How I may separate the `reactions` taken from any `KeyPressed or KeyReleased`within a `panel` and to call it as a method, when it's needed within a `panel`? I have this piece of code that I want to separate:

```
listenTo(keys, mouse.moves, mouse.clicks)
reactions += {
  case kpr: KeyPressed =>
    if (kpr.key == Key.Up) upPressed = true
    if (kpr.key == Key.Down) downPressed = true
  case krl: KeyReleased =>
    if (krl.key == Key.Up) upPressed = false
    if (krl.key == Key.Down) downPressed = false
  case me: MouseEntered => requestFocus
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell which API you're using, but I've previously used the java.awt.event.KeyListener API. I think you may find my pattern useful.

```
class InputHandler extends KeyListener {
  val keys = ArrayBuffer[Key]()

  class Key {
    keys += this

    var down = false

    def toggle(pressed: Boolean) {
      down = pressed
    }
  }

  val up = new Key
  val down = new Key
  val garbage = new Key

  def releaseAll() {
    keys.foreach(_.down = false)
  }

  def keyForEvent(e: KeyEvent): Key = e.getKeyCode match {
    case KeyEvent.VK_W => up
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP => up
    case KeyEvent.VK_S => down
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN => down
    case _ => garbage
  }

  // for the listener interface equivalent:
  def toggle(e: KeyEvent, pressed: Boolean): Unit = keyForEvent(e).toggle(pressed)
  def keyPressed(e: KeyEvent): Unit = toggle(e, true)
  def keyReleased(e: KeyEvent): Unit = toggle(e, false)
  def keyTyped(e: KeyEvent) {}
}
```

I had other state to maintain how much time keys were held down, if it was a fresh click, etc... You can likely model the same. I don't think you can get rid of mapping key code to `Key` instance; you may very well want to use a HashMap instead and let your users update the key mappings.

**Edit: Try saving the commands as a PartialFunction**

```
val commonReactions = {
  case kpr: KeyPressed =>
    if (kpr.key == Key.Up) upPressed = true
    if (kpr.key == Key.Down) downPressed = true
  case krl: KeyReleased =>
    if (krl.key == Key.Up) upPressed = false
    if (krl.key == Key.Down) downPressed = false
  case me: MouseEntered => requestFocus
}

reactions += commonReactions
```

Comment: I am using `scala.swing.event._`

Comment: I am already using in every derived GUI that kind of `reactions` and I am getting bored from copy-ing and past-ing it in each GUI so I would like just to know how to put aside as a method and then to call it :(

Comment: Without a larger code sample I'm afraid I can't offer more.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're asking. It looks like `reactions` might be a list of `PartialFunction`. See my edit.

Comment: Hi @Nate, your Edit is EXACTLY what I am searching for, but the problem is that I have tried the same thing and I am getting this compiler error just in the beginning of expression: `missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was: ?` I thought it's not functional in this way? !!

Comment: Fine, I just added at the end: `val commonReactions = ({ //same...   } :Reactions.Reaction)` and it's fine now! Thankssss!

Comment: Now I am wondering why it's not functional for the last `case`: `case me: MouseEntered => requestFocus` ? I made the compiler not to complain but when I execute the APP it generate errors!!!

Comment: @Val unfortunately I'm not familiar with the scala swing API. I'd recommend dropping in a breakpoint and see what's going on.